# upgrade magneto 2.3.4 to magneto 2.3.5 after upgrade customer not create in admin

Tags: magento2.3, customer-account

I am try to create a customer in admin, and customer-created successfully, but stuck in customer create form and error happened

[image]

Comment: Have you checked var/log ?

Comment: yes I am checked, nothing found regarding the error

Comment: its maybe because of dropdown attribute => class of trade ? has it all options showing inside it ?

Comment: @DineshRajput - yes all options are displayed